# Why Gmail Password field couldnt be sent keys with "sendkeys" in Selenium Webdriver (Java)?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Am getting error as "Element is not visible" while running below code.

When I checked through google and on some investigation, found that Password is coming with "Password-hidden" attribute. How do I get rid of this.

```
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Email']")).sendKeys("ashwinxxxxx@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='next']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys("abcd2123");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signIn']")).click();
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you change XPath expression to "//*[@id='Passwd']" ?

Comment: No. No Luck adding any element finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find element using id as below:

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
element1.sendKeys("Password");
```

If it fails, post the exception or error being received.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
element1.sendKeys("Password");
```

Comment: Same exception as before - "Element is not visible"

Comment: try to use explicit wait. I have modified answer as required.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned the answer above with all details. Can't accept my answer for 2 days. Can u pls do

Answer (score 0):

Below Explicit wait worked.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        WebElement element1 = wait.until(
                ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Passwd")));
        element1.sendKeys("xxxxxx");
```

Classes to be imported are:

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

Answer (score 0):

I used WebDriver Wait and changed the locater  from 'id' to 'xpath'

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement MyPass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")));
MyPass.sendKeys("Password");
```